# undefined variable on calling function

Tags: c

I'm trying to create this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void suffix(char str[], char c);

int main()
{
   char ch;
   char str[100] ="abcdefgabcd";
   ch=c;
   suffix(str,ch);

   return 0;
}

void suffix(char str[], char c)
{
    int length;
    int i;
    int j;
    int counter=0;


    for (length=0; str[length]!='\0';)
    { 
        length++;
    }


    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==c)
        {
           counter++;
           /* print */
           for(j=i; j<length;j++)
           {
              printf("%s",str[j]);
           }
           printf("\n");
        }  
     }
```

I want to link between `main` and `suffix` functions so I added arguments datatypes as variable `c`.
Now on the `main` program I have to link suffix with the arguments so I created a variable named `ch` which stores the value of `c` on suffix.
Now, to do this I must call suffix on `main`, But I have to call it with its arguments (or else I would get `too few arguments in function call`).
But, if I want to call suffix I have to store `c` in `ch`, but I can't do this because main doesn't know suffix.
This is a "dragged problem", I can't do each ways because there are errors each way.
How can I solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just assign a character to `ch`, and pass `ch` to the function? Or just pass a character-literal directly? It's not really clear what you want with this `c` variable in `main`.

Comment: `c` is `ch` on main, I have problem with the storage because `suffix` should be declare before but if I declared it before, I have to send `ch` and `ch` doesn't have any value.
It's probably due my misunderstanding

Comment: @rolory, c is _nothing_ in main. main doesn't know anything about argument names of other functions, and cannot know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments in C cannot get modified by subroutines, but you can provide the address of those arguments instead; the subroutine can modify memory at the provided address. This is called "pointers" and it's a subject that cannot be adequately taught in a stack overflow post.

To summarize how pointers would get used in this case though, you would change your subroutine's call signature to be: `void suffix(char str[], char *c)` (notice the `*` next to the c variable); you would change your call in `main` to be: `suffix(str, &ch);` (send the address of your `ch` variable), and you would change all uses of the `c` variable in `suffix` to be `*c` (instead of looking at `c`, you're now looking at what `c` points to).

One of the reasons this subject is far too complicated to learn from a post is: *pointers are dangerous when misused*, and it's very easy to misuse them when you don't know what you're doing! Misuse of pointers can cause your program to crash, sometimes for reasons that are not obvious, and it can cause other data in your program to be changed in ways you did not intend (which could indirectly lead to a crash, or just incorrect results).

```
void suffix(char str[], char *c)    /* <--- notice the change on this line */
{
    int length;
    int i;
    int j;
    int counter=0;


    for (length=0; str[length]!='\0';)
    { 
        length++;
    }


    for(i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(str[i]==*c)   /* <--- and this line */
        {
           counter++;
           /* print */
           for(j=i; j<length;j++)
           {
              printf("%s",str[j]);
           }
           printf("\n");
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: I really didn't understand how can I improve the code in the `main()`
Probably I'm getting ahead of myself. I haven't learned about pointers and whatever yet

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use string.h, it is standard.
[strcat()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/?kw=strcat) does exactly what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char str1[13] = "abcdef";
  char str2[7] = "uvwxyz";
  strcat(str1, str2);
  printf("%s\n", str1);
  return 0;
}
```